# how UIImageJPEGRepresentation() works

Tags: ios, uiimagejpegrepresentation

A 700x700 png image, shows imageview cost of 1.88Mib memory, but if I compress it with UIImageJPEGRepresentation(data, 0.9), the memory cost decreases to 736Kib but the image size unchanged, the jpg pixel has no alpha, but the cost of memory decrease almost 62%, I want to know how UIImageJPEGRepresentation() works? thx

load png image:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bbb" ofType:@"png"];
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:NULL];
UIImage * img = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

load jpg image

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"bbb" ofType:@"png"];
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path options:NSDataReadingMappedIfSafe error:NULL];
UIImage * img = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
img = [UIImage imageWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0.9)];
```

jpg memory cost:

[image: jpg memory cost]

png memory cost:

[image: png memory cost]

Comment: How do you measure the *memory cost*? Where are the numbers 1.88MB and 736KB from?

Comment: What’s the surprise? JPEG is compressed. That means smaller.

Comment: @Codo Instruments Allocations,
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/gifUE.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/c24Xk.png

Comment: @matt Yea, but how it compressed?

Comment: Mostly by using discrete cosine transform. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_cosine_transform

Comment: @matt: 1.88MB is the uncompressed size. So I don't think that your arguments apply.

Comment: @Codo I'm not making any arguments. It seems the OP does not know what a JPG is.

Answer (score 0):

`UIImage imageWithData:` will decompress the PNG file. The resulting size matches the resolution:

> 700 pixels × 700 pixels × 4 byte/pixel = 1,960,000 = 1.87 MByte

This image is no longer related with the PNG format and compression technique.

The second example first decompresses the PNG file and then compresses it using the JPEG algorithm. The result is ⁠– of course ⁠– smaller as it is compressed.

Both JPEG and PNG are algorithms for compressing images. You will find a lot of documentation online about how they work. It's far from trivial...

Comment: I thought the memory of compressed image could be figured,it seems wrong